# Is bounced email same as Delivery status notification Failure?

Tags: email

Is bounced email same as Delivery status notificaiton Failure or are those two different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing..."bounced" is the slang for and NDR.

Comment: Actually a "bounce" is the process of rejecting an incoming mail, while a non-delivery report (or a delivery status notification for a delivery failure) is just a result of this process.

Comment: Actually a bounce is one type of NDR, but is commonly used to refer to any NDR...at least by lay people.